# I am trying to make a swing text editor. Everytime the font gets to big it resizes my JTextArea I am using and messes up the entie layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window

I am trying to make a swing text editor. Everytime the font gets to big it resizes my JTextArea I am using and messes up the entie layout. Is there any way to lock the pages size vertically and horizontaly? I tried wrapping it but that barely works and it only goes horizontaly. I looked on google and other resources and could not find anything to help me.

```
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Font;
 import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

  import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
 import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JMenu;
 import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
 import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;

 public class Other extends JFrame {

 //create menu variables
 static JMenuBar bar;
 static JMenu fileMenu;
 static JMenu textMenu;
 static JMenuItem saveFile;
 static JMenuItem newFile;
 static JCheckBoxMenuItem boldRadio;
 static JCheckBoxMenuItem italicsRadio;
 static JMenuItem sizeOptions;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size8;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size9;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size10;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size11;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size12;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size14;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size18;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size24;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size30;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size36;
 static JRadioButtonMenuItem size48;
 static JTextArea txtArea;

 //fonts
 static Font font8;
 static Font font9;
 static Font font10;
 static Font font11;
 static Font font12;
 static Font font14;
 static Font font18;
 static Font font24;
 static Font font30;
 static Font font36;
 static Font font48;

 //arrays


  Other(){
    super("Text Editor");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    add(panel);
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    txtArea = new JTextArea(41,45);
    txtArea.setEditable(true);
    panel.add(txtArea);
    txtArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
    txtArea.setLineWrap(true);

    //base menu bar code here
    bar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(bar);
    bar.setForeground(Color.BLACK);

    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    bar.add(fileMenu);

    textMenu = new JMenu("Text");
    bar.add(textMenu);
    textMenu.setOpaque(true);
    textMenu.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(null,5));

    //menu items code here
    saveFile = new JMenuItem("Save File");
    fileMenu.add(saveFile);
    saveFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

    newFile = new JMenuItem("New File");
    fileMenu.add(newFile);
    newFile.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);

    boldRadio = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Bold");
    textMenu.add(boldRadio);
    boldRadio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);

    italicsRadio = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Italics");
    textMenu.add(italicsRadio);
    italicsRadio.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_I);

    sizeOptions = new JMenu("Text Size");
    textMenu.add(sizeOptions);
    sizeOptions.setSize(500,500);

    ButtonGroup sizesG = new ButtonGroup();

    size8 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("8");
    size9 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("9");
    size10 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("10");
    size11 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("11");
    size12 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("12");
    size14 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("14");
    size18 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("18");
    size24 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("24");
    size30 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("30");
    size36 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("36");
    size48 = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("48");
    size11.setSelected(true);

     for(JRadioButtonMenuItem x: sizes) {
            sizesG.add(x);
            sizeOptions.add(x);
            x.addItemListener(new sizeClass());
    }

    font8 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,8);
    font9 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,9);
    font10 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,10);
    font11 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,11);
    font12 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,12);
    font14 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,14);
    font18 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,18);
    font24 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,24);
    font30 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,30);
    font36 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,36);
    font48 = new Font("Serif",Font.PLAIN,48);
   }

    class sizeClass implements ItemListener{

     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if(size8.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font8);
        }else if(size9.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font9);
        }else if(size10.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font10);
        }else if(size11.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font11);
        }else if(size12.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font12);
        }else if(size14.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font14);
        }else if(size18.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font18);
        }else if(size24.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font24);
        }else if(size30.isSelected())  {
            txtArea.setFont(font30);
        }else if(size36.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font36);
        }else if(size48.isSelected()) {
            txtArea.setFont(font48);
        }

      }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtArea = new JTextArea(41,45);
txtArea.setEditable(true);
panel.add(txtArea);
```

When you create the JTextArea you are suggesting a default size of the text area. As the text in the text area changes you need the text area to be able to grow. So you should be adding the text area to a scroll pane.

Your code should be something like:

```
txtArea = new JTextArea(41,45);
//txtArea.setEditable(true); // this is the default
//panel.add(txtArea);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( txtArea );
panel.add( scrollPane ):
```

Also, get rid of the static keyword on all your variables. It is not needed and should not be used.

Don't create all those variables for the font size. You can create generic code for your ItemListener. Something like:

```
JRadioButtonMenuItem button = (JRadioButtonMenuItem)e.getSource();
float size = Float.parseFloat(button.getText();
Font font = txtArea.getFont();
txtArea.setFont( font.deriveFont( size) );
```